# Creating a dictionary from 2 lists in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dictionary from 2 lists, **departements** list (a list of strings) as *keys* and **users** list (a list of objects) as *values*.

Here is the snippet

```js
let departments = ['IT','HR'];
let users = [{'name' : 'John', 'depart':'IT'}, {'name' : 'Mary', 'depart':'HR'}, {'name' : 'Carlos', 'depart':'HR'}, {'name' : 'James','depart':'HR'}];


//expected result
let dict = {
  'IT': [{'name' : 'John'}],
  'HR': [{'name' : 'Mary'}, {'name' : 'Carlos'} {'name' : 'James'}]
};
```

Comment: Hi!  Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What is logic behind? What will happen if length of `users`  is 6

Comment: i added a depart value in users but why would i filter or sort out by depart ?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the users:

```js
const dict = {};
for (const user of users) {
    if (user.depart in dict) {
        dict[user.depart].push(user);
    } else {
        dict[user.depart] = [user];
    }
    // if you don't want the depart property in the final output uncomment this line
    // delete user.depart;
}
```

Comment: i added a depart value in users but why would i filter or sort out by depart ?

Comment: I appreciate your time with this brilliant answer, thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through departments and filter users to extract users in departments.

```
let departments = ['IT','HR'];
let users = [{'name' : 'John', 'depart':'IT'}, {'name' : 'Mary', 'depart':'HR'}, {'name' : 'Carlos', 'depart':'HR'}, {'name' : 'James','depart':'HR'}];


//expected result
let dict = {
  'IT': [{'name' : 'John'}],
  'HR': [{'name' : 'Mary'}, {'name' : 'Carlos'}, {'name' : 'James'}]
};

var depDictionary ={};
for (let index = 0; index < departments.length; index++) {
  const department = departments[index];
  depDictionary[department] = users.filter(function(user){ 
    return user.depart == department;
  }).map(function(user){
    return {name:user.name};
  });
}
```